# Is it possible to use a custom filter function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Can I use my helper function to determine if a shot was a three pointer as a filter function in Pandas?  My actual function is much more complex, but i simplified it for this question.

```py
def isThree(x, y):
    return (x + y == 3)

print data[isThree(data['x'], data['y'])].head()
```

Comment: I looked at that, but my actual function is pretty big and I want to be able to reuse it.  I didn't think a lambda would work.  Are there other options within apply?

Comment: Use numpy.vectorize which is amazingly fast.

Comment: @JSells you never *have* to use a `lambda`, in fact Guido apparently wanted to remove the construct in Python 3. You can do anything with a function created with a full function definition that you can with a `lambda`, except of course, making that function anonymous (which is never something that *has* to happen). Put in any event `.apply` is not necessary here. It is usually a last-resort

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma um, no it is not. [`numpy.vectorize` is a convenience method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), it even states right there in the docs "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: Is the goal here to subset the original DataFrame or assign some new column based on the Boolean value?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The more complex your functions get the more you will see that the performance won't be that different as over here it is stated that the function is complex.

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma I don't see that, and in any case, there are better solutions, like using `pd.DataFrame.query`, if you are worried about too many intermediate arrays

Comment: @ALollz i am trying to filter out certain rows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(1,3,10),
                     'y': np.random.randint(1,3,10)})
print(data)
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  2  1
3  1  2
4  2  1
5  2  1
6  2  1
7  2  1
8  2  1
9  2  2
```

```
def isThree(x, y):
    return (x + y == 3)

print(data[isThree(data['x'], data['y'])].head())
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  2  1
3  1  2
4  2  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as your function returns a Boolean Series with the same index  you can slice your original DataFrame with the output. In this simple example, we can pass `Series` to your function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 4, (30, 2)))
def isThree(x, y):
    return x + y == 3

df[isThree(df[0], df[1])]
#    0  1
#2   2  1
#5   2  1
#9   0  3
#11  2  1
#12  0  3
#13  2  1
#27  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would recommend using `np.where()`. See the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,4,2,3,1,2,3,4,0], 'y': [0,1,2,0,0,2,4,0,1,2]})

df['3 Pointer'] = np.where(df['x']+df['y']==3, 1, 0)
```

Yields:

```
   x  y  3 Pointer
0  1  0          0
1  2  1          1
2  4  2          0
3  2  0          0
4  3  0          1
5  1  2          1
6  2  4          0
7  3  0          1
8  4  1          0
9  0  2          0
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer as the question states "My actual function is much more complex, but i simplified it for this question." So basically he wants to use some other function.

Comment: This accurately answers the question at hand and given a more complex function, there is still no concrete reason given by the OP that `np.where()` would not suffice.

Comment: agree with @rahlf23 I see no reason why this would not be valid

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma is correct.  Would there be a way to include 'isThree' in a where call?

Comment: @JSells yes, the same exact way you did `isThree(data['x'], data['y'])`. Both boolean indexing and `np.where` accept boolean arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to python which may be why I was having trouble getting the other proposed solutions to work, but what worked for me was:

```
for index in range(len(data.index)):
    x = data.loc[index, 'x']
    y = data.loc[index, 'y']

    if not isThree(x, y):
        data = data.drop(index)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use  np.vectorize. Documentation  is here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

```
def isThree(x, y):
    return (x + y == 3)

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[2,0]})
df['new_column'] = np.vectorize(isThree)(df['A'], df['B'])
```

Comment: This doesn't actually vectorise anything (in terms of performance).

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but is there also a way to filter without creating a new column?  If not, this works well too.

Comment: @JSells do **not** use `np.vectorize` here. There is no need, *the operations are already vectorized*, and this function is essentially a python-level for-loop

Comment: @JSells I don't see anyway to filter without creating a column. I would suggest using other solutions if that's your ultimate goal. Also I would suggest you to try this and look for the performance and how it works for you!