# How to filter rows by custom function Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a custom regex Python function that checks is it email or not:

```
def isEmail(str):
  return True;
```

I want to iterate all rows in Pandas dataframe and validate the column `email`. and return count ofvalid rows (true/false).

I have found `apply()` Pandas function.

I try to leave only rows where column email has correct email address:

```
def isEmail(str):
    return re.search('regex', str)

    dt[isEmail(dt['email'])])
```

Then call this again to count how much incorrect rows to put into Python set:

```
incorrectEmails = {emails: 0}
count = dt[isEmail(dt['email'])])
incorrectEmails.set(count)
```

Comment: `df2 = df[df['email'].apply(isEmail)]`? `count = df['email'].apply(isEmail).sum()` or do you have a specific question?

Comment: Probably yes, I just want to count how much emails wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

[Is it possible to use a custom filter function in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463399/is-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-filter-function-in-pandas)

You can try adding a global counter inside the `is_email()` function to count how many falses were provided and use `.apply()` on the `email` column.

```
dt2 = dt[dt['email'].apply(is_email)]
```

Comment: Thank you, in this solution I did not get how to return count to `dict varaible: dict_ = {wrongEmails: 2}` if I check email column

Comment: Can you please explain more with the actual code in order for me to better understand this

Comment: Yes, see my updation